# How to do string operations when aggregating a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to perform some aggregations on a pandas dataframe. I'm using pandas version 1.3.3.

It seems I am only able to use builtin python functions, such as the `max` function, to aggregate columns that contain strings. Trying to do the same thing using any custom function (even one that only calls the builtin `max`) causes an error, as shown in the example below.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this example, and what is the correct way to use a custom function for string aggregation?

```
import pandas as pd

# Define a dataframe with two columns - one with strings (a-e), one with numbers (1-5)
foo = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'string_col': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        'num_col': [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
)


# Custom aggregation function to concatenate strings
def custom_aggregation_funcion(vals):
    return ", ".join(vals)


# This works - gives a pandas Series with string_col = e, and num_col = 5
a = foo.agg(func={'string_col': max, 'num_col': max})

# This crashes with 'ValueError: cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously'
b = foo.agg(func={'string_col': lambda x: max(x), 'num_col': max})

# Crashes with same error
c = foo.agg(func={'string_col': custom_aggregation_funcion, 'num_col': max})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to run:

```
foo['string_col'].agg(','.join)
```

you will see that you get back a Series:

```
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
Name: string_col, dtype: object
```

Indeed, your custom function is applied per element, not on the whole Series. Thus the "*cannot perform both aggregation and transformation operations simultaneously*".

You can change your function to:

```
# Custom aggregation function to concatenate strings
def custom_aggregation_funcion(vals):
    return ", ".join(vals.to_list())

c = foo.agg(func={'string_col': custom_aggregation_funcion, 'num_col': max})
```

output:

```
string_col    a, b, c, d, e
num_col                   5
dtype: object
```